# How to make a class return the value of a property when it is called

Tags: python, python-3.x

So lets say we have a class with @property value. How do it make it return the value of a property when it is called

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        # name = self.name
        print('Value is : ')
        return self._value

    @value.getter
    def read(self):
        print('running custom read function')
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def write(self, val):
        print('running custom write function')
        self._value = val
```

What i expect is when we call myclass it will return the property value instead

```
>>> x = myclass('test')
>>> x
'running custom read function'
'test'
>>> x = 'test2'
'running custom write function'
>>> x
'test2'
```

Comment: That isn't *calling the class*. That is just referencing a variable, which will always evaluate to that object.

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? I do not think it is possible within Python. It is close to have `__str()__` but not sure if that's what you need.

Comment: You are not calling myclass, you are a calling an object of myclass.  as @digitplumber says, you can write __str__ and __repr__ functions for your class, so when you print them, they return a specific value.  but just the reference will just get you the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really do this but you can use an alternative '__str__':

```
class Nothing:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

test = Nothing("test")
print(test)

#to change value
test.value = value
print(test)
```

for more details visit [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str\_\_#object.__str\_\](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str%5C_%5C_#object.__str%5C_%5C)_

**disclaimer**: I don't know much about classes

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem as stated

Comment: yeah i realised

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your [`property`](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3.9/library/functions.html#property) usage, `@value.getter` is invalid.

```py
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def read(self):
        print('running custom read function')
        return self._value

    def write(self, val):
        print('running custom write function')
        self._value = val

    value = property(read, write)
```

Add the magic method [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) to achieve the following results.

```
>>> x = myclass('test')
>>> x
'running custom read function'
'test'
```

The following result is not achievable in my current knowledge... I think it's just a simple variable assignment operation.

```
>>> x = 'test2'
'running custom write function'
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Added magic method `__call__`, do not know if the questioner will need.

Comment: That isn't what the OP is asking. What they seem to want isn't possible

Comment: Hmmm what needed was the ability to call the custom read and write function when the class it called. just editted the question

Comment: @Jonathan I just modified it and need your confirmation. If you are not satisfied with it, I will delete it.

Comment: below is the outcome.. maybe i will have to reference the whole x.value to a variable hmmm
>>> x.value
running custom read function
'test'
>>> x.value='lalala'
running custom write function
>>> x.value
running custom read function
'lalala'